# Can I use only CD 1 Debian (600 mb) to do offline install?

Tags: linux, debian

My pendrive only has 2GB of capacity and I dont have internet connection at home, so I cant do a net-install. With only CD1 from https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd can I install Debian without internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use debian-10.2.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso, the answer is yes. However it only comes with the lightweight xfce desktop enviroment. If you would like GNOME you would have to get it installed and then when you get to a place with internet you would then need to install gnome-desktop.

Comment: Will the network manager and overall driver work? also I don't need graphical environment.

Comment: It should work just fine.

Comment: Very well, thank you Sir.

Comment: @user394346 Your welcome.